# vscode + go: cannot find package, cannot import function

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-modules

I have a vscode workspace with a couple of go modules. I have a top-level `go.work` file.
I have installed the go plugin and installed all its dependencies. I have initialized separate modules in the workspace and have ran `go use` to add all the modules to my `go.work` file.

Unfortunately I didn't realize packages were generally named like "github.com/my-org/my-package/utils" etc. So I just have simple module names like `xservice` and `yservice` etc. Inside one such module folder, I have:

- `main.go` <-- *package main* at the top
- `go.mod`
- `go.sum`
- `/folder1`
- `/folder1/utils.go` <- *package main* at the top + contains function `DoSomething()`

**Inside main.go**: how do I call `DoSomething()`? **vscode** will not let me import it or call it, not matter what I do in terms of paths or module names. And it is part of the same module.

Please note that this question is because the example given here: https://go.dev/doc/code does not work. As in, I can't seem to get it to work in vscode with a top-level `go.work` file.

### Update

Was asked for a reproducible example per comment below. I was putting it together and saw that when I use `package main` everywhere, in the module, it wouldn't compile
[image]

When I followed the directory structure and reflected that in the package names per the answer below it worked (i.e. make `foo.go` belong to `package utils` instead).

Comment: If it is part of the same module, what are you doing with `go.work`? You don't need to use github to name a module, just import the package as `modulename/packagename`. Walk through [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code), which explains this exact scenario step by step.

Comment: @JimB because there are other modules. I am trying to learn go **microservices**, where several modules are developed in parallel, so this isn't the only module.  `modulename/main` did not work: **no required module provides package modulename/main** error in vscode.

Comment: `modulename/main` doesn't look like anything you've described so far. If the docs don't help show what our mistake was, you need to create a [mre] so we can see what exactly you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vs code is not an IDE, it is a text editor.
it happens very often, that some minor misconfiguration breaks down the whole Intellisense.

that' why i suggest to first start with reducing the amount of "View->Problems" to 0.

in go all packages are folders. for that reason i assume your IDE complains about package misconfiguration

> /folder1/utils.go <- package main at the top

in my opinion `utils.go` should contain `package folder1`

the project structure is equal the folder structure. when you use `xservice` and `yservice` i expect to find 2 folders with the respective names.
see [an example](https://earthly.dev/blog/go-workspaces/#refactor-with-go-workspaces)

to achieve that, i suggest to use the power of go and not try to initialize stuff manually. when executed properly, go can [generate a module](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-init) for you.

when you are in a `module`, you can simply access any subpackage.

the example would be like:

```
main.go <- package "main" at the top
go.mod <- module "whatever"
/folder1/utils.go <- package "folder1" at the top, contains function DoSomething()
```

then you can simply call `folder1.DoSomething()` in main.
on the logic of go, you have a `module` called "whatever" which has an executable main and a `package` "folder1" with `DoSomething`.

Comment: I was just following @JimB's advice to create a small reproducible and I just drew the same conclusion as you that, it turns out that putting `package main` everywhere is stupid and that packages are supposed to reflect the folder structure.